# How do I append an element to a KList?

Tags: scala, generics, types, functional-programming, shapeless

How do I append an element to a `KList` while maintaining the original type of the KList? I'm still new to shapeless and am really unclear on what types to expect from a function.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do. I want to use a type constraint to ensure all values conform to `Box[_]`, but I also tried an unconstrained example using a plain `HList` and still can't get it to compile.

```scala
import shapeless._
import shapeless.UnaryTCConstraint.*->*

case class Box[T](value: T)

case class BoxBuilder[B <: HList](boxes: B) {
  def add[T](box: Box[T]): BoxBuilder[HList] = {
    this.copy(boxes = boxes :+ box)
  }
}

case class BoxBuilderTC[B <: HList : *->*[Box]#λ](boxes: B) {
  def add[T](box: Box[T]): BoxBuilder[HList] = {
    this.copy(boxes = boxes :+ box)
  }
}
```

I'm probably missing some of the basics of shapeless here so any other tips/advice is more than welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add necessary implicit parameters / context bounds

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.UnaryTCConstraint.*->*
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Prepend

case class Box[T](value: T)

case class BoxBuilder[B <: HList](boxes: B) {
  def add[T](box: Box[T])(implicit prepend: Prepend[B, Box[T] :: HNil]): BoxBuilder[prepend.Out] = {
    this.copy(boxes = boxes :+ box)
  }
}

case class BoxBuilderTC[B <: HList : *->*[Box]#λ](boxes: B) {
  def add[T, Out <: HList : *->*[Box]#λ](box: Box[T])(implicit
                                        prepend: Prepend.Aux[B, Box[T] :: HNil, Out]
  ): BoxBuilderTC[Out] = {
    this.copy(boxes = boxes :+ box)
  }
}
```

Normally writing just `HList` instead of specific subtype of `HList` is too rough.

Comment: Ah, excellent – this is exactly what I was looking for. I'll just leave a note here for future readers FWIW. It appears that IntelliJ reports a 'Type mismatch' error for the unconstrained example here even though the compiler doesn't. It says: `Type Mismatch. Required: prepend.Out. Found: Prepend[B, Box[T] :: HNil]#Out`. I'm not clear why it doesn't consider those two as equivalent. It doesn't report a similar error for the constrained example.

Comment: @AlanThomas They are not equivalent. The former is a subtype of the latter. (This is related to IntelliJ and not Scala).

Comment: @AlanThomas, I have the same issue with version 2019.2, with 2020.1 it doesn't happen. But with the constrained example, it gives an error.